# Может ли личное местоимение быть общей частью сложносочинённого предложения?

Tags: запятые

Он поднял голову (,) и сжал кулаки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Личное местоимение в данном случае отдыхает.

У нас простое предложение с основой *он поднял и сжал*, где "он" - подлежащее, "поднял, сжал" - сказуемые.

***Он поднял голову и сжал кулаки.***

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Меня просто смущает существительное "кулаки". Если убрать "он", то запятую следует ставить?

Comment: А "голова" не смущает? ))) Поднял голову, сжал кулаки - существительные здесь в роли дополнения.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы ^^ У меня была мысль, что это дополнение, просто в русском языке вообще не ориентируюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: Если убрать "он", получится неполное предложение, без подлежащего. ***Поднял голову, сжал кулаки.***

Comment: Буду теперь знать. Когда учился, вообще эти нюансы не понимал. Благодарствую!

Comment: Тогда треугльничек верхний кликните - у ответа! )))

Comment: Потому что, видимо, запятая ставится, когда есть разные грамматические основы, где принимают участие подлежащее и глагол. И, как я понял, дополнение в эту грамматическую основу главную не входит, поэтому сложносочинённого предложения из него не составить. Я это понимаю так на данный момент. Может, я и не прав :)

Comment: К сожалению, у меня рейтинг низкий, уже кликал... :(

Comment: Зато нажал галочку :3

Comment: Ромыч, две основы и создают сложносочинённую связь (если нет подчинения). Ср.: ***Он поднял голову, и соперник сжал кулаки.*** А когда общее слово или даже предложение, иначе: ***После очередного обмена репликами он поднял голову и соперник сжал кулаки.*** Или: ***Когда пауза затянулась, он поднял голову и соперник сжал кулаки.*** Спасибо за галочку. )))

Comment: Пожалуйста. Спасибо за ответы и внимание! ^_^